# Ktor Server: How to find out when a client has finished downloading a file?

Tags: ktor

I want to run code when a HTTP client has finished downloading a file from Ktor Server. The most simple approach does not work:

```kotlin
routing {
    get("/download") {
        call.response.header(
            ContentDisposition,
            Attachment.withParameter(FileName, file.fileName).toString()
        )
        call.respondFile(file)
        // client has not finished downloaded when we reach this point
    }
}
```

I already tried intercepting pipelines, writing out the file in byte arrays myself, but all that detects a completed download too soon. If I for example stop the webserver and related services too soon, the client isn't able to actually complete the download.

So is there a way to reliably detect when the client has ACKed the last bytes of the file?

Comment: So do you want to gracefully shut down a server so clients could complete downloading of resources?

Comment: Right, if there's no general way of getting notified when a download has completed, shutting down a server after download has completed would also do the trick.

Comment: You can try to call the `stop` method https://api.ktor.io/ktor-server/ktor-server-host-common/io.ktor.server.engine/-application-engine/stop.html with a huge number like `Long.MAX_VALUE` as the second argument.

Comment: If I do this, Ktor doesn't seem to stop the server at all, at least not in a reasonable amount of time. Ideally, the completed download is recognized less than a minute after it completed.

But after several minutes, the webserver still hasn't stopped, even after terminating the browser process.